# Java error, cannot find feild user2303583

Tags: java

Hi I am trying to get my code to create the  new constructor objects which i reqiure to create mobile phone object, I have tried naming the constuctor fields to create object, however Error comes up at

```
public Mobile(String Mobilephonetype, String Mobilescreensize,
        String Mobilememorycardcapacity, String Mobilecameraresolution,
        String MobileGPS), at the bottom of the page
```

why am i getting this error?

```
java error, cannot find symbol - variable samsung
```

UPDATE i have changed some of the top fields from private int to string but now it says cannot find symbol - class string, what doers this mean??

Code:

```
/**
 * to write a simple java class Mobile that models a mobile phone.
 * 
 * @author () 
 * @version (14/10/13)
 */
public class Mobile

{
    // type of phone
    private string phonetype;
    // size of screen in inches
    private int screensize;
    // menory card capacity
    private int  memorycardcapacity;
    // name of present service provider
    private string serviceprovider;
    // type of contract with service provider
    private int typeofcontract;
    // camera resolution in megapixels
    private int cameraresolution;
    // the percentage of charge left on the phone
    private int checkcharge;
    // wether the phone has GPS or not
    private string GPS;
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private int x;

    // The constructor method

    public Mobile(String mobilePhoneType, int mobileScreenSize,
            int mobileMemoryCardCapacity, String newserviceprovider, int mobileCameraResolution,
            String mobileGPS) {
        this.phonetype =  mobilePhoneType;
        this.screensize = mobileScreenSize;
        this.memorycardcapacity = mobileMemoryCardCapacity;
        this.cameraresolution = mobileCameraResolution;
        this.GPS = mobileGPS;

        // you do not use this ones during instantiation,you can remove them if you do not need or assign them some  default values 
        this.serviceprovider = newserviceprovider;
        this.typeofcontract = 12;
        this.checkcharge = checkcharge;

    }

    // A method to display the state of the object to the screen
    public void displayMobileDetails() {
        System.out.println("phonetype: " + phonetype);
        System.out.println("screensize: " + screensize);
        System.out.println("memorycardcapacity: " + memorycardcapacity);
        System.out.println("cameraresolution: " + cameraresolution);
        System.out.println("GPS: " + GPS);
         System.out.println("serviceprovider: " + serviceprovider);
        System.out.println("typeofcontract: " + typeofcontract);

    }

    public Mobile(String MobilephoneType, int Mobilescreensize, int Mobilememorycardcapacity, String newserviceprovider, int Mobilecameraresolution,
            String MobileGPS) {
        this.phonetype = Mobilephonetype;
        this.screensize = 3;
        this.memorycardcapacity = 4;
        this.cameraresolution = 8;
        this.GPS = GPS;
        this.serviceprovider = newserviceprovider;
        this.typeofcontract = 12;
        this.checkcharge = checkcharge;


    }

}

 class mymobile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Mobile Samsung = new Mobile("Samsung", "3", "4", "8",
                "GPS");
        Mobile Blackberry = new Mobile("Blackberry", "3.", "4",
                "8", "GPS");
        Samsung.displayMobileDetails();
        Blackberry.displayMobileDetails();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please *don't* name methods with names starting with an uppercase letter.

Comment: `cannot find symbol - class string, what doers this mean??` Exactly what it says. There is no class `string`. Maybe you did mean `String`?

Answer (score 2):

This line seems to be problem in `public Mobile` method:

```
this.phonetype = Samsung;
```

since you're defining `Samsung` object inside main method in `class mymobile` which is not available in `class Mobile`

**UPDATE:** I sincerely advise you to start using a IDE like Eclipse so that these type of errors can be caught in the editor itself.

Most like instead of this declaration:

```
// type of phone
private int phonetype;
```

You meant:

```
// type of phone
private String phonetype;
```

and then use this assignment:

```
this.phonetype = Mobilephonetype;
```

Comment: Hi  i have used Eclipse before, but my tutor says we have to use Bluej editor to create this for this work.

Comment: You can use any other IDE also. Did you try my suggestion to fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such variable `Samsung`. In this line:

```
 this.phonetype = Samsung;
```

It seems as though you may have meant to assign `Mobilephonetype` to it somehow, but as the comment below suggest, it's an `int`.

Comment: `Mobilephonetype` is String argument actually.

Comment: Hi I've just tried replacing it with Mobilephonetype and it have given  the following error message: incompatible types

Comment: `phonetype ` is `int ` variable

Answer (score 0):

The problem looks to be `this.phonetype = Samsung;`, try changing it to `this.phonetype = Mobilephonetype`.

Comment: Hi I've just tried replacing it with Mobilephonetype and it have given the following error message: incompatible types

Comment: UPDATE i have changed some of the top fields from private int to string but now it says cannot find symbol - class string, what doers this mean??

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have problem with your constructor,you should use parameters which you pass  to constructor.You can change them related your needs and also assign parameters to appropriate class variables

In your main method you instantiate an instance named Samsung as below

```
Mobile Samsung = new Mobile("Samsung", "3", "4", "8",
            "GPS");
```

This is true way to instantiate an instance.You pass parameter to constructor when you instantiate an instance.So you should pass parameters right way in your constructor like this

```
  public Mobile(String mobilePhoneType, int mobileScreenSize,
            int mobileMemoryCardCapacity, int mobileCameraResolution,
            String mobileGPS) {
        this.phonetype =  mobilePhoneType;
        this.screensize = mobileScreenSize;
        this.memorycardcapacity = mobileMemoryCardCapacity;
        this.cameraresolution = mobileCameraResolution;
        this.GPS = mobileGPS;

        // you do not use this ones during instantiation,you can remove them if you do not need or assign them some  default values 
        this.serviceprovider = newserviceprovider;
        this.typeofcontract = 12;
        this.checkcharge = checkcharge;


    }
```

You have incompatible type variables according to your parameter passing,you can change them as below

```
private String phonetype;
private int screensize;
private int  memorycardcapacity;
private int cameraresolution;
private String GPS;
```

Comment: Hi yes i did but when I compile it says cannot find symbol - class string, I have uploaded the edited updated code

Comment: You should remove **Mobile Samsung = new Mobile("Samsung", "3", "4", "8",
            "GPS");** top of the constructor

Comment: Also you should other things too,remove  **public Mobile(String Mobilephonetype, String Mobilescreensize,
            String Mobilememorycardcapacity, String Mobilecameraresolution,
            String MobileGPS) {
        this.phonetype = Mobilephonetype;
        this.screensize = 3;
        this.memorycardcapacity = 4;
        this.cameraresolution = 8;
        this.GPS = GPS;
        this.serviceprovider = newserviceprovider;
        this.typeofcontract = 12;
        this.checkcharge = checkcharge;


    }**

Comment: Ok i have removed the above and replaced have amended the code but i still get error cannot find symbol- class string

Comment: Also you did not declare `newserviceprovider` variable and you try to use it

Comment: Ok i have declared the newserviceprovider variable and updated the above code but it still says:  cannot find symbol- class string

Comment: i have declared the newserviceprovider variable and updated the above code but it still says: cannot find symbol- class string,                                                                    my code wont compile at all now, any suggestions on how to fix my code? as i dont know any solutions

Answer (score 0):

The types of private instance fields 'phonetype', 'serviceprovider' and 'GPS' should be 'String' and not 'string'.